# Why is there no Cybernetics site on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering why there was no cybernetics site on here given that we have sites for hardware, firmware, software, even wetware (medical sci). It seems to me like we have all the prerequisites from math and linguistics to AI, bioinformatics and operations research! I mean we even have bio-acoustics (so don't come at me saying: "cybernetics is too niche")!

I'm a simple fellow, and I'd like to talk about communication and control in animals and machines,  brain computer interfaces, and cyber-physical-systems (from the perspective of science not fiction). And if there is anywhere on the internet nerdy enough for this topic it would be here.

So I most humbly ask: why not?

Comment: This board exists to discuss philosophy, not stack exchanges policy.

Comment: Because there is [AI stack exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions). See [What happened to cybernetics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12057/55) on HSM.

Comment: Naturally, there will be a classification error for a cross-disciplinary subject. Apologies, I agree that this topic does not fall strictly under philosophy, but where does it go? One cannot say that cybernetics is subsumed under AI, since AI does not adequately address issues of biological or social intelligence.